# Remove all escape sequences in specific code block

Tags: python, regex

I have an HTML snippet which looks like the following:

```
<code class="inline">\n     object.__getattribute__\n    </code>\n    and\n    <code class="inline">\n     super.__getattribute__\n    </code>\n    peek\nin the\n    <code class="inline">\n     __dict__\n    </code>\n    of classes on the MRO for a class when looking for\nan attribute. This PEP adds an optional\n    <code class="inline">\n     __getdescriptor__\n    </code>\n    method to\na metaclass that replaces this behavior and gives more control over attribute\nlookup, especially when using a\n    \n     super\n    </a>\n\n    \n    </a>\n    object.\n   </p>\n<p>\n    That is, the MRO walking loop in\n
```

**Question**

How can I target just the `\n` in the `<code>` tags?

**What I've tried**

I have tried to use the `re.sub()` method but I keep replacing all of the contents instead of just the `\n` tags

Comment: Your question is far from precise. Replace all escape sequences with what?  Sample output would probably do it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant remove, not replace.

Comment: Do you want to remove just the `<code>` and `</code>`, or everything in between as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the input is HTML, why don't use a specialized tool - an *HTML parser*.

Here is a sample on how you can locate all `code` tags and replace `\n` with an empty string using [`BeautifulSoup` HTML parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<code class="inline">\n     object.__getattribute__\n    </code>\n    and\n    <code class="inline">\n     super.__getattribute__\n    </code>\n    peek\nin the\n    <code class="inline">\n     __dict__\n    </code>\n    of classes on the MRO for a class when looking for\nan attribute. This PEP adds an optional\n    <code class="inline">\n     __getdescriptor__\n    </code>\n    method to\na metaclass that replaces this behavior and gives more control over attribute\nlookup, especially when using a\n    \n     super\n    </a>\n\n    \n    </a>\n    object.\n   </p>\n<p>\n    That is, the MRO walking loop in\n"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for code in soup("code"):
    code.string = code.string.replace("\n", "")

print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = '<code class="inline">\n     object.__getattribute__\n    </code>\n    and\n    <code class="inline">\n     super.__getattribute__\n    </code>\n    peek\nin the\n    <code class="inline">\n     __dict__\n    </code>\n    of classes on the MRO for a class when looking for\nan attribute. This PEP adds an optional\n    <code class="inline">\n     __getdescriptor__\n    </code>\n    method to\na metaclass that replaces this behavior and gives more control over attribute\nlookup, especially when using a\n    \n     super\n    </a>\n\n    \n    </a>\n    object.\n   </p>\n<p>\n    That is, the MRO walking loop in\n '

print(text.replace('\n',''))
```

Comment: Note: the OP asked about removing `\n` inside `<code>...</code>` only..